# Where does the name "B-Tension" come from?

Tags: derailleur, terminology

Why is the "B-Tension" adjustment screw so called? Does it stand for anything, have there been A and C adjustments, or is there another reason for its name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The B-screw is for "Body screw", since it affects the body angle of the derailleur.

B-Tension is Shimano's term for B-screw -- as Sheldon points out, on Campagnolo, the screw behaves the opposite of Shimano.

See [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html) and [Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment#article-section-4) for more details. Also, see [the answer here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24270/misadjusted-b-screw-symptoms) for more details on what it does.